# JQuery UI Autocomplete only works in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, autocomplete

I'm using Jquery UI Autocomplete and it works perfectly in IE8 but it works in IE8 ONLY. Can anyone shed any light on this.  My code is below but even with no options it still doesn't work.  Jquery 1.5

```
$("#instructor_number").autocomplete({
source: "autocompleteInstructor.php",
minLength: 2,
select: function( event, ui ) {
    $("#db_instructor_number").attr("value", ui.item.id);
    $(".approvedCentreRow").slideDown("fast");
    accentre();
    }

});
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by does not work. Do you see an error, does it make the ajax request, does it reach the server....etc etc. Have you checked firebug or chrome inspector? We need more info.

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap the code in this:

```
$(function() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: You do not have to, better to include the js at the bottom of the dom.

Comment: Sorry yes, all is wrapped in $(document).ready etc. this is just a snippet.  In very simple terms, when I start typing in the textbox no autocomplete appears....not even attempts.   The page loads fine in IE8 however if I click compatibility mode the page loads with a javascript error, as it does in other browsers.

Comment: @redsquare ~ I guess it's a matter of preference, but since jQuery is being loaded anyway, the markup overhead to add a document ready callback + add the script along with the others in `head` is pretty small. I'm somewhat more inclined to go that path and keep my markup [seemingly] organized.

Comment: @richardneililagan well I disagree, adding to the ready queue does add overhead and I have seen so much code using multiple ready events in partials the devs get confused what is supposed to fire when! I stay away from any ready events and use namespaced init events to keep the js organised and be in control over which events get called when

Comment: @redsquare ~ hmmm, yeah, that's a pretty valid point. I mean, if you've got explicitly defined slots in your lifecycle to call inits, I'd do that as well. +1 I do appreciate that, and if there's something I'd like to see with `ready`, it's to be able to specify ready hooks on explicit elements, instead of bubbling everything up the document ready hook.

Comment: Sorry to cause a stir.  Using IE8 debugger I found it actually relates to some other offending code on the page (but within the same overall function).  The problem was between datepicker and UI on the same page being initialised from the same function.